# Blank Data Source Manager Window

Tags: qgis

Sometimes, when opening the **Data Source Manager** window, I get only the Header, everything else is blank, **there is no access to any tab or... anything at all**. I got the problem in earlier versions and still have it in 3.10 LTR. I can't link that problem to anything I do, it seems to happen randomly but I guess it's not.

**Closing and reopening QGIS does not fix the problem. I have to reboot the computer.**

Did this ever happen to anybody else?

[image]

I realised that resizing the windows does fix the problem temporarily. It is still blank the next time.

Is there a way to fix it other than rebooting the computer?
What causes this to happen?

Comment: Have you checked the bug reports for QGIS? Have you tried wiping everything QGIS-related before reinstalling the newest LTR?

Comment: Have you checked the Log Messages? There might be something useful stated in there, such as a missing library.

Comment: I have not had this issue. Is this on Windows? Have you tried QGIS 3.12? How have you installed QGIS?

Comment: Windows 10 - Standalone installer

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Go to the Data Source Manager toolbar >>
Click on Data Source Manager (first icon) >>
Go to Browser (uppermost tab) >>
Click on Refresh (second icon)

Then go back to the layer you wanted to edit: right-click Change Data Source and the window will be filled with your available option.